# Installation of imagemagick with BREW

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

My problem is really simple :)

```
schovi@Saskia:~/tmp $ brew install imagemagick
Error: You must install
brew install git

schovi@Saskia:~/tmp $ brew install git
Warning: Formula already installed: git

schovi@Saskia:~/tmp $ brew install imagemagick
Error: You must install Git:
brew install git
```

Any idea? :)

Comment: What's the output of `which git`?

Comment: Also, did you install homebrew to `/usr/local` ?

Comment: And PATH is `/Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin:/Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/bin:/Users/schovi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin:/Users/schovi/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/schovi/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install git from http://git-scm.com/

Comment: Better. I thought that brew is some kind of magic apps that can gandle everything :D

Comment: Actually, it's likely that it did, but wasn't installed in a location on your path.