# Using brew with Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, imagemagick, homebrew

I'm trying to get ImageMagick with Homebrew, but I keep getting errors. Then I did a "brew doctor" and I get:

> Ruby version 1.9.2 is unsupported.
>
> Homebrew is developed and tested on Ruby 1.8.x, and may not work
>   correctly on Ruby 1.9.x. Patches are accepted as long as they don't
>   break on 1.8.x.
>
> ==> `/usr/bin` occurs before `/usr/local/bin` This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those provided by
>   Homebrew. This is an issue if you eg. brew installed Python.
>
> Consider editing your .bashrc to put:   `/usr/local/bin` ahead of
>   `/usr/bin` in your PATH.

Can this really be true?

If so, what are my other options here?

Comment: It's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872447/error-undefined-method-when-installing-imagemagick-through-homebrew/8873435#8873435 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884601/validating-a-pictures-size-in-ror-without-imagemagick . Why are you creating duplicates of your own questions?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In the first one, I'm asking why I can't install ImageMagick through Homebrew and in the second one I'm asking if there's another way to validate a pictures size without using ImageMagick. Here I'm asking if it's really true that Homebrew simply doesn't work with version 1.9.2 of Ruby. Can you tell me if that's the case?

Comment: I certainly have... I just posted the full error I get after doing brew doctor in the main post -->

Comment: First of all, you've already got an answer : you should try to upgrade your homebrew via "brew update". My version of brew doesn't complain on rubies v 1.9.2 and v 1.9.3 and everything works fine. Also you should consider adding /usr/local/bin to the beginning of your PATH variable.

Comment: Have done brew update. What is my PATH variable?

Comment: My typing speed is too low. Try to add /usr/local/bin to your path in your .bashrc as it said in "brew doctor" output.

Comment: Mine too :-). I'm very sorry for being so noobish, but where is my .bashrc-file?

Comment: Usually in your home directory: `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I've got one under the user I'm logged into, but not in my home directory. When I open it, it says:  $HOME
[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && . $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Comment: How about `~/.bash_profile`? Is there a line that says `export PATH=[a bunch of directories]`

Comment: If I do ~/.bash_profile? in the terminal, I get: -bash: /Users/holgersindbaek/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you replaced the system ruby on your mac? The `brew` executable has `#!/usr/bin/ruby` at the start, so it should be using the system ruby, which is 1.8.7.

Comment: I do think I have yes. It's not under the normal path. How do you re-install the system ruby? Delete Xcode and install it again?

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk I don't know how to reinstall system ruby, but if you have changed it that will be your problem. Try to find out how to reinstall the system 1.8.7 ruby, then if you want to use other versions use something like rvm to install them alongside, but leave the system version alone! Homebrew uses 1.8.7 as this is the system version, so it can be assumed it already exists, and Apple also install some ruby files as part of the OS which may depend on the version. Note ruby isn't installed as part of XCode, it's part of the base OS install.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the comments thread has gotten too long, I'm going to type the rest of the answer here. First, try adding `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH before `/usr/bin`. As the error message above indicates, doing this allows your system to call the programs installed by homebrew before the system-provided ones. For example, if you install Python via `brew python`, but don't change the PATH, your system will look first in `/usr/bin`, see Python there, and won't look any further. It'll miss the version you installed in `/usr/local/bin` with homebrew.

Changing your PATH on Mac OS X is a little different than on other systems. There's a good answer [here at Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard) on changing the PATH in Mac OS X. Look in the files mentioned in the linked question's top answer (`/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`)
 to find where your PATH variable is defined, and move `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`. For example, if your `~/.bash_profile` has a line that looks like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin
```

You'll want to change it to move `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, like so:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin
```

Setting and changing the PATH is less about programming than it is about Mac OS X system administration, thus falling out of the scope of Stack Overflow. If you run into problems, or are still confused, I'd recommend asking a question on http://apple.stackexchange.com. There are a lot of very experienced Apple users there who are familiar with system administration in Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very thorough answer. I'll give it a try first thing in the morning. Thanks again :-).

Comment: Another tip for others. After you have added the above code to your .bash_profile file close the terminal and reopen it so the changes can take place.

Comment: Amazing answer Michael. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Comment from Sathya in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard) post helps me. Instead of anything else. Look in the `/etc/paths` file.