# Failed to install rmagick

Tags: ruby, compilation, rubygems, compiler-errors

My env:`rvm ruby 1.9.2` , and I build `ImageMagick 6.7.4-6` from source.

When I install rmagick, it says:

> /home/rocky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>   You have to install development tools first.

However, I also have ruby `1.8.7` in my rvm, and the rmagick can be installed correctly in 1.8.7. So I'm very confused what I missed in 1.9.2.

Comment: My answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872447/error-undefined-method-when-installing-imagemagick-through-homebrew might help.

Comment: Sounds like Ruby is having trouble finding the GCC compiler so it can't compile the RMagick source code.  You'd have to look and see how to set that, possibly using `setenv`... not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael's answer, the key is to configure ImageMagick with this:

> ./configure --disable-static --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8

Answer (score 1):

Try following

Hope, Your environment is ububtu

sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

gem install rmagick

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, my environment is AndLinux. Which is not update for a long time. The repository only has a very old imagemagick, actually, that's why I need to compile from source.